# Underline formatting option should be implemented in all the SE sites

Tags: discussion, feature-request, code-formatting

**Bold** and *italics* simply aren't enough. This is especially true in the case of websites on the sciences and languages, where a lot of explanation needs to be provided. The formatting package should come with all the three options: bold *and* italics *and* underline.

#### **Underline should be included in the formatting package of all SE sites**.

My reasons **for** it:

- When you've **bold**ed and *italicise*d as  much as you possibly could and still have other things to highlight, you run out of options. Overusing bold ad italics doesn't look very good. Italicising isn't a sensible alternative to underlining, since it isn't that noticeable. To set apart the most significant piece of text within a writing that's bolded and italicised all over, you need a distinct formatting.

  For instance, consider this [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/134438/how-to-understand-which-words-or-phrase-brackets-point-to). Compare this

  [image: Without underline]

  with this

  [image: With underline]

  Anyone who remotely understands style and how formatting works will agree the underline looks better and serves a very useful purpose.
- The major argument against the use of underline is that they can be easily confused with links. Yes, possible — but people using the computer for quite some days should easily be able to distinguish. (Even if they can't, the misunderstanding doesn't have any serious consequences. Everybody eventually gets that.) If the difference between a hyperlink and a simple underline were so foggy, HTML and MS Word wouldn't have supported *underline*. And besides, [hyperlinks](http://google.com) in SE don't have underlines so it's highly unlikely that an average user would fail to differentiate between them.

Comment: Can you give specific examples where you feel underlining is necessary? Thanks.

Comment: Fun fact: It **is** actually available in one site, [Japanese.SE](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1294).

Comment: @Laurel That isn't even *normal* underline.